# Jest encountered an unexpected token with OpenLayers import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, openlayers, babel-jest

[image: The Error]

[image: Error Soure]

I read this error thoroughly and followed up on a number of posts, but the solutions don't seem to work for me. Here is what I've read the potential cause is:

1. https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7401

I've tried to update my Jest configuration in my package.json as well installed jest-canvas-mock, but still encounter this error. Here are the changes I've made:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(ol)/)"
],
"setupFiles": [
  "jest-canvas-mock"
],
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep dive I was able to come across the core issue in detail here:

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6229#issuecomment-551916758

This issue is still relevant, so for posterity sake I'll provide the technique I discovered for applying the band-aid:

1. Rename your .babelrc to babel.config.js (Note that you have to use module.exports)
2. Apply the desired transformIgnorePattern:

   "transformIgnorePatterns": [
   "/node_modules/(?!ol).+\.js$"
   ],

If this doesn't work you the link above should guide you towards a solution.